# create a class Table for an inexisting table slick scala (Slick 3.0.0, scala)

Tags: database, scala, slick, slick-3.0

Assume that we have a database which contains two tables: `Coffee` and `Suppliers` and we have their corresponding case classes and tables, just as in the documentation:

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.lifted.{ProvenShape, ForeignKeyQuery}


// A Suppliers table with 6 columns: id, name, street, city, state, zip
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name: Column[String] = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street: Column[String] = column[String]("STREET")
  def city: Column[String] = column[String]("CITY")
  def state: Column[String] = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip: Column[String] = column[String]("ZIP")

  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}

// A Coffees table with 5 columns: name, supplier id, price, sales, total
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name: Column[String] = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID: Column[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price: Column[Double] = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales: Column[Int] = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total: Column[Int] = column[Int]("TOTAL")

  def * : ProvenShape[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = (name, supID, price, sales, total)

  // A reified foreign key relation that can be navigated to create a join
  def supplier: ForeignKeyQuery[Suppliers, (Int, String, String, String, String, String)] = 
    foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, TableQuery[Suppliers])(_.id)
}
```

Now assume that we want to do a join:

```
   val result = for {
       c <- coffees
       s <- suppliers if c.supID === s.id
} yield (c.name, s.name)
```

And here dealing with the result is complicated ( and it's more complicated if we have a lot of joins) because we need always to remember the order of names, to know what  `_._1` or `_._2` refer to ... etc.

**Question 1** Is there a way to change the type of the result as a table of a new class which contains the desired columns ?

**Question 2** Here is a way but I can't finish it, we construct a case class for example:

```
case class Joined(nameS: String,nameC: String)
```

and after that we construct the corresponding table which I don't know how

```
class Joineds extends Table[Joinedclass] {
//Todo
}
```

and when we write a join we can write something like ( so that we can transform result to a type Joined) :

```
   val result = for {
       c <- coffees
       s <- suppliers if c.supID === s.id
} yield (c.name, s.name).as(Joinds)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you define it like:

```
val result = for {
  c <- coffees
  s <- suppliers if c.supID === s.id
} yield Joined(c.name, s.name)
```

And the tuck it away in some convenient place?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I solved the problem in another way but actually your example is interesting, the type of `result` is `Seq[Joined]`?

Comment: You would be able to get a Seq[Joined] after you run the query and wait for the future to be completed, yes. Good to hear you solved it!